# Paths in Heroku deployment

Tags: heroku, go

I am trying to deploy a test golang app to Heroku:

[image]

My procfile looks like this:

```
web: todo
```

But when running my app I get the following error:

```
2017-04-10T15:24:07.128780+00:00 app[web.1]: panic: could not locate box "./static"
```

My *main.go* file contains:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/server"
    "github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice"
    "os"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "path"
    "strconv"
)

var boxPrefix = getenv("BOXPATH", "")

func main() {
    dir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("DIRECTORY CWD: " + dir)
    ex, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    exPath := path.Dir(ex)
    fmt.Println("EXECUTABLE PATH: " + exPath)
    exists, err := exists(boxPrefix + "static")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("CHECK IF (" +boxPrefix + "static) EXISTS: " + strconv.FormatBool(exists))
    server.RegisterHandlers()
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(rice.MustFindBox(boxPrefix + "static").HTTPBox()))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func getenv(key, fallback string) string {
    value := os.Getenv(key)
    if len(value) == 0 {
        return fallback
    }
    return value
}

func exists(path string) (bool, error) {
    _, err := os.Stat(path)
    if err == nil {
        return true, nil
    }
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return false, nil
    }
    return true, err
}
```

Can someone give me an hint ?

**EDIT**: Here the output when I try to find the CWD and set the box path accordingly

```
2017-04-10T17:23:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-04-10T17:24:06.341977+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `go-todoist`
2017-04-10T17:24:08.592486+00:00 app[web.1]: DIRECTORY CWD: /app
2017-04-10T17:24:08.595689+00:00 app[web.1]: panic: could not locate box "static"
2017-04-10T17:24:08.595691+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T17:24:08.595692+00:00 app[web.1]: goroutine 1 [running]:
2017-04-10T17:24:08.595718+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/vendor/github.com/GeertJohan/go%2erice.MustFindBox(0x71e08d, 0x6, 0x0)
2017-04-10T17:24:08.595721+00:00 app[web.1]:    /tmp/tmp.Pa1igbANNl/.go/src/github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/vendor/github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice/box.go:110 +0x94
2017-04-10T17:24:08.595724+00:00 app[web.1]: main.main()
2017-04-10T17:24:08.595741+00:00 app[web.1]:    /tmp/tmp.Pa1igbANNl/.go/src/github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/main.go:21 +0x1a8
2017-04-10T17:24:08.660495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2017-04-10T17:24:08.685016+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-04-10T17:24:08.686277+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-04-10T17:24:09.023202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `go-todoist`
2017-04-10T17:24:10.743837+00:00 app[web.1]: DIRECTORY CWD: /app
2017-04-10T17:24:10.746355+00:00 app[web.1]: panic: could not locate box "static"
2017-04-10T17:24:10.746357+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-04-10T17:24:10.746360+00:00 app[web.1]: goroutine 1 [running]:
2017-04-10T17:24:10.746361+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/vendor/github.com/GeertJohan/go%2erice.MustFindBox(0x71e08d, 0x6, 0x0)
2017-04-10T17:24:10.746361+00:00 app[web.1]:    /tmp/tmp.Pa1igbANNl/.go/src/github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/vendor/github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice/box.go:110 +0x94
2017-04-10T17:24:10.746363+00:00 app[web.1]: main.main()
2017-04-10T17:24:10.746367+00:00 app[web.1]:    /tmp/tmp.Pa1igbANNl/.go/src/github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/main.go:21 +0x1a8
2017-04-10T17:24:10.791994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2017-04-10T17:24:10.817345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
vagrant@precise64:/code/src/github.com/kitensei/go-todoist$ heroku run bash -a go-todoist-gpr
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:119: warning: Insecure world writable dir /code/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Running bash on ⬢ go-todoist-gpr... up, run.9334 (Free)
~ $ cd /app
~ $ pwd
/app
~ $ ls -lA
total 48
-rw------- 1 u52460 dyno  289 Apr 10 17:23 .gitignore
drwx------ 3 u52460 dyno 4096 Apr 10 17:24 .heroku
drwx------ 2 u52460 dyno 4096 Apr 10 17:24 .profile.d
-rw------- 1 u52460 dyno   15 Apr 10 17:24 Procfile
-rw------- 1 u52460 dyno   26 Apr 10 17:23 README.md
-rw------- 1 u52460 dyno  326 Apr 10 17:23 app.json
drwx------ 2 u52460 dyno 4096 Apr 10 17:24 bin
-rw------- 1 u52460 dyno  592 Apr 10 17:23 main.go
drwx------ 2 u52460 dyno 4096 Apr 10 17:23 server
drwx------ 3 u52460 dyno 4096 Apr 10 17:23 static
drwx------ 2 u52460 dyno 4096 Apr 10 17:23 task
drwx------ 3 u52460 dyno 4096 Apr 10 17:23 vendor
~ $
```

Trying to run the app on the Heroku bash:

```
~ $ go-todoist
DIRECTORY CWD: /app
EXECUTABLE PATH: /app/bin
CHECK IF (static) EXISTS: true
panic: could not locate box "static"

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/vendor/github.com/GeertJohan/go%2erice.MustFindBox(0xc4200f0cf0, 0xb, 0x5)
        /tmp/tmp.FmcU3dgw8Y/.go/src/github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/vendor/github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice/box.go:110 +0x94
main.main()
        /tmp/tmp.FmcU3dgw8Y/.go/src/github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/main.go:34 +0x42c
```

The same with an absolute path:

```
~ $ go-todoist
DIRECTORY CWD: /app
EXECUTABLE PATH: /app/bin
CHECK IF (/app/static) EXISTS: true
panic: given name/path is absolute

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/vendor/github.com/GeertJohan/go%2erice.MustFindBox(0xc4200f0cf0, 0xb, 0x5)
        /tmp/tmp.FmcU3dgw8Y/.go/src/github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/vendor/github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice/box.go:110 +0x94
main.main()
        /tmp/tmp.FmcU3dgw8Y/.go/src/github.com/kitensei/go-todoist/main.go:34 +0x42c
```

Comment: If I remember correctly your project files are stored in an `/app` folder but the app itself does not necessarily have to be started from that folder, which will cause the error you're getting. On the heroku dashboard set an env var, something like `PROJECT_PATH=/app` and then in your main.go file use the `os` package to read that value... I'm not 100% sure about the `/app` location so try spinning up a one-off `bash` dyno on that app and explore the folders a little.

Comment: Please see my edits about the log of CWD on heroku

Comment: I also tried to find the executable path `which go-todoist` which gaves me `/app/bin` but even when using `../static` as box path I get the same error

Comment: What do you get if you try using the full path? That is, `/app/static`. Also did you run the one off dyno with `bash` to check whether there is a `static` folder in the `/app` folder?

Comment: The `go.rice` library doesn't support abs path for the box. And yes there is a static dir inside app folder (see the end of the logs)

Comment: I take my previous comment about the absolute paths back, i see here now https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice/blob/master/box.go#L31-L35 that they are indeed not supported.

Comment: Hmm you might be out of luck here... go.rice seems to resolve the path by using the `$GOPATH` variable, but the heroku go buildpack that sets the `$GOPATH` on each deploy sets it to a value that does not include the `/app` contents... I think you'll have more luck raising an issue on the go.rice github page. Sorry

Comment: I will, I have temporary switched to `http.Dir` which works great (but was causing me troubles with Vagrant, but that's another story ;) )